# Kivy - How to tag a button or event with custom metadata / information?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

***TLDR: Is there a good way to add custom metadata to buttons (or any widget) in Kivy?***

In Kivy, I have something set up such that my app will dynamically generate a set of buttons, based on a particular 'tag' selected (in this example, I pass the "Fruits" tag).

2 lists are then generated. The first list is the name of the elements (e.g. the name of the fruits). The second list is a unique identifier for that element (the data is pulled from some master database that has all this information linked together).

I then have a class method that generates buttons in a GridLayout, based on the list of items generated.

```
#This section is in the .py file

itemNameList = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry"]
itemUniqueIDList = ["Unique1", "Unique2", "Unique3"]

for ProductName,ProductUniqueID in zip(itemNameList,itemUniqueIDList):
    #For each element in the list of products
    #add a button widget to the WidgetID instance
    WidgetID.add_widget(
        Button(
            id=ProductUniqueID,#THIS IS THE POTENTIAL ISSUE
            text=ProductName,
            on_press=self.on_press_Product_Select_Button
        )
    )
```

Now, I'm trying to set up my code such that I always try to use the unique identifier to pull any other information required (e.g. if I want the price of 'Cherry', I want to reference the unique ID, and use that to pull price information). Thus, when I press a button like 'Cherry', I also want to obtain the unique ID of 'Cherry'. My current workaround for this is to set the ID of the Button as the unique ID of the item the button corresponds to.

As such, when one of these dynamically generated buttons is pressed, I pull the text (e.g. 'Cherry') and the associated unique ID (e.g. 'Unique3'), as below:

```
#This section is in the .py file

def on_press_item(self, instance):
    #Method that will be called when a button of an item (e.g. the 'Cherry' button' is pressed

    ProductName = instance.text #Returns 'Cherry'
    ProductUniqueID = instance.id #"Returns 'Unique3'
```

However, I notice that I am getting the following warning, and I suspect it's because I am setting the id of the button when generating the button (because when I comment that row out, the Warning no longer appears):

```
[WARNING] Deprecated property "<StringProperty name=id>" of object "<kivy.uix.button.Button object at 0x000001EB791BC388>" has been set, it will be removed in a future version
```

For reference, here is the part of the .kv file that then interacts with this section of the code:

```
#This section is in the .kv file

GridLayout:
    id:menu_item_button_layout
    cols: 4

    on_parent:
        root.GenerateProductButtons(WidgetID=menu_item_button_layout)
```

Edit: Had some errant text to remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set a normal attribute.

```
button = Button(...)
button.my_custom_attr = 'value'
```

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly the right answer. I don't know how I hadn't found it in the documentation before.